# How to rotate an image in a picturebox?

Tags: vb6, rotation, image

I have a picture in a PictureBox. I want to rotate it by any angle.
And auto resize the PictureBox according to the rotated picture dimension.
Is there any sample code/project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rotate images inside of pictureboxes and I believe auto resizing is a property you can easily select on pictureboxes. A sample project that shows rotating images can be found here:

http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=25764&lngWId=1

Comment: YA, i have seen this project. Its really good and fast too. The only problem is that autoresize dont work! And setting the X & Y co-ordinatyes is so confusing that i'm unbale to get the pefect cordinates :(

Comment: Isn't resizing literally like... picking the AutoSize property to true? EDIT: or is it AutoRedraw? I'm fairly certain this doesn't even need code to happen, literally select one of the properties to true.

Comment: Not for a picture box, it requires 1 line of code to resize to fit the picture size.